# Python : XLRD; compare the columns length

Tags: python, xlrd

I'm using `xlrd` to work on xls files. My xls file has got two columns and my requirement is to make sure both the columns have got equal number of rows. I learnt from `help()` that we have got a `row_len()` to look for the length of a row given with the index, but unable to find any for `col_len`. Can you please help with any

Here is my code

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
spread_sheet=open_workbook("simple.xls")
sheet1=spread_sheet.sheet_by_index(0)

#validates the no of columns in the Spread sheet
 if sheet1.ncols == 2:
  for sheet1_rows in range(sheet1.nrows):
    for sheet1_cols in range(sheet1.ncols):
        value=sheet1.cell(sheet1_rows,sheet1_cols).value
        source=sheet1.cell(sheet1_rows,0).value
        destination=sheet1.cell(sheet1_rows,1).value
    #ignores the Source and Destination Headers 
    if value not in ('Source','Destination'):
        print "Source is : %s \nDestination is : %s\n" %    (source,destination)
 else:
  print "XLS provided is not valid. Check the no of columns is 2"
```

Some other options apart from comparing the below please

```
>>> print len(sheet1.col_values(0))
8
>>> print len(sheet1.col_values(1))
8
```

---

Thanks for your reply @alecxe. Instead adding few more lines to my code, I found out something below. please advise will this work out

```
 >>> print len(sheet1.col_values(0))
 6
 >>> print len(sheet1.col_values(1))
 6
 >>> sheet1.col_values(0)
 [u'A', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0]
 >>> sheet1.col_values(1)
 [u'B', 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, '']
 >>> print len(filter(None,sheet1.col_values(1)))
 5
 >>>
```

Comment: What is wrong with `len(sheet1.col_values(0))`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MikeMuller. Since I'm a newbie to Python, I'm trying to learn all BIFs which saves the effort. Just curious to know if any existing in Python other than `len(sheet1.col_values(0))`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by column length? There can be empty cells anywhere.

Comment: I think you should just check that every cell has a valid value.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `len(sheet.col_values(index))` for measuring how many cells are set in the column (column length). `col_values` length is always equal to `sheet.nrows`.

Imagine you have the following in the `input.xls`:

```
A B
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
  2
```

Then `len(sheet.col_values(0))` will return 5 (as well as `len(sheet.col_values(1))`), which is incorrect. Should be 4.

Instead, it's better to use something like this:

```
from itertools import takewhile
import xlrd


def column_len(sheet, index):
    col_values = sheet.col_values(index)
    col_len = len(col_values)
    for _ in takewhile(lambda x: not x, reversed(col_values)):
        col_len -= 1
    return col_len


book = xlrd.open_workbook("input.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

print column_len(sheet, 0)  # prints 4
print column_len(sheet, 1)  # prints 5
```

Hope that helps.