# Python: Using xlrd library to read data from excel spreadsheet gives me incorrect number of rows

Tags: python

I was using the xlrd library to read a workbook. I used the following code to read the columns and rows containing words and put it into a dictionary:

```
import xlrd

EXCEL_FILE = "Hangman_words.xlsx"

def main():
    """Main application entry point."""
    # To open Workbook 
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(EXCEL_FILE) 
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
    
    word_dict = {}
    
    for i in range(sheet.ncols):
        try:
            #print(sheet.cell_value(0, i))
            category_name = sheet.cell_value(0, i)
            if not category_name:
                break
            word_dict[category_name] = []
            for j in range(sheet.nrows):
                try:
                    #print(sheet.cell_value(j+1, i))
                    word = sheet.cell_value(j+1, i)
                    if not word:
                        break
                    word_dict[category_name].append(word)
                except:
                    break
        except:
            break

    print(word_dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In my excel file, column 1 goes all the way to row 51, column 2 goes all the to row 53 and column 3 goes all the way to row 38. However, in my python code, the range(sheet.ncols) is set to (0,3) and range(sheet.nrows) is set to (0,53) and this row number is not correct for each column because as described previously, it varies.

[image]

My code also throws an exception for column 2. Hence I had to set up some exceptions and if conditions to ensure that the code will break out of the loop incase if there's any error or if there's a blank cell.

Since, I am pretty new to using this xlrd library, I was wondering if there is a way to get the correct number of rows for each column that I can iterate through? Or if there's a better xl library that can outperform the current library that I am using. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : XLRD; compare the columns length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915864/python-xlrd-compare-the-columns-length)

Answer (score 0):

"the range(sheet.ncols) is set to (0,3) and range(sheet.nrows) is set to (0,53) "
--Correct. xlrd would only limit the data range from 1stRow1stCol to 53rdRow3rdCol

What makes trouble is that you have null values at the bottom of your columns. You have to analyze it and stop it from further reading.

"My code also throws an exception for column 2"

```
            for j in range(sheet.nrows):
                try:
                    #print(sheet.cell_value(j+1, i))
                    word = sheet.cell_value(j+1, i)
```

as j comes to the last of range(53), j=52
sheet.cell_value(53, 0)
Of course it breaches the data range in xlrd, since the nrow is limited to
0,1,...,52
A correction would be:

```
            for j in range(1, sheet.nrows):
                try:
                    #print(sheet.cell_value(j, i))
                    word = sheet.cell_value(j, i)
```